# Is there a way to SkipLinesAtEnd in a TextFormat Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

We receive Text files from a external partner.
They claim to be csv but have some difficult pre-header and footers.

In a ADF TextFormat I can use "skipLineCount": 6, But at the end i'm running in troubles ...

Any suggestions ?

Can't find something like SkipLinesAtEnd ....

This is the Sample

```
TITLE : Liste de NID_C_BG_NPIG configuré.
FILE NAME : Ines_bcn_npig_net_f.csv
CREATION DATE : 09/10/2019 23:18:43
ENVIRONMENT : Production 12c
<Begin of file>
"NID_C";"NID_BG";"N_PIG"
"253";"0";"0"
"253";"0";"1"
"253";"1";"0"
"253";"1";"1"
"253";"2";"0"
"253";"2";"1"
"253";"3";"0"
<End of file>
```

Comment: Is this in a Copy activity or a Data Flow? In a Data Flow, you can use Alter Row to delete the row based on a condition (perhaps check the text value of the first column?"

Comment: I did not yet use DataFlow for this as it should have been pretty straight forward. I'm a bit afraid of the costs for a data-flow running quite often. But will have to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `skipLineCount` setting in Data Flow.No feature like `skipLinesAtEnd` in ADF.

You could follow suggestion mentioned by @Joel that using Alter Row.

[image]

However,based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row),it only supports database mode sink.

[image]

So,if you are limited by that,i would suggest you parse the file first before copy job.For example,add an [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to cut the extra rows if you know the specific location of header and foot.Inside the Azure Function,just use the code to alter the file.

Comment: Thx, will have to work something out like that, as there is no way the input files can be changed.... Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Jay & Joel are correct in pointing you toward Data Flows to solve this problem. Use Copy  Activity in ADF for data movement-focused operations and Data Flows for data transformation.

You'll find the price for data movement similar to that of data transformation.

I would solve this in Data Flow and use a Filter transformation to filter out any row that has the string "" in it.

Should not need an Alter Row in this case.  HTH!!